# Linear search error with arrayBound of exception

Tags: java, linear-search

This is my linear search code but I am getting an error with the array. I know what the error is and I have fixed it, but it still shows the same error:

> Runtime Error: Runtime ErrorException in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5   at
>   LinearSearchExample.linearSearch(LinearSearchExample.java:13)     at
>   LinearSearchExample.main(LinearSearchExample.java:40)

```
    public class LinearSearchExample
    {    
        public static int linearSearch(int[] arr, int key)
        {    
                for(int i=1;i<=arr.length;i++)
                    {    
                        if(arr[i] == key)
                            {    
                                return i;    
                            }    
                    }    
             return -1;    
         }  

    public static void main(String a[])
        { 
                int i, n, key, arr[],testcase;
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                testcase = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println(testcase);

                for(i=0;i<testcase;i++)
                {
                        n = in.nextInt(); 
                        arr = new int[n];

                        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                        arr[i] = in.nextInt();

                        }

                        key = in.nextInt();

                    System.out.println(linearSearch(arr, key)); 

                }   
        }    
}
```

Comment: array index goes from 0 to arr.length - 1

Answer (score 3):

Java arrays are 0 based.  Fix your loop in `linearSearch()`

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
```

Your second and third loops do this correctly :)

Comment: thanks it worked...just a small glitch i want to pass this code though 2 testcases....the code is returning answer for the 2nd testcase only where i am wrong?